# docker run creating a new data volume for each run

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I would like to persist some configuration data from a container and am following the tutorial on [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

I'm successfully running the app with:

```
docker run -it --privileged -v /app/config -p 8083:8083 myapp-ubuntu:2.2.2
```

Where `-v /app/config` is the directory inside the container that contains the config that should survive a container restart.

Also the result of running the container creates a volume in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

```
# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes
5e60d70dc15bcc53aa13cfd84507b5758842c7743d43da2bfa2fc121b2f32479
```

However, if I kill the container and rerun it no data is persisted and a new volume is created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`:

```
# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes
5e60d70dc15bcc53aa13cfd84507b5758842c7743d43da2bfa2fc121b2f32479  (FIRST RUN)
82de3aa910bc38157a6dc20a516b770bd0264860ae83093d471212f69960d02a  (SECOND RUN)
```

I would expect that these would be the steps for persisting, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve it with [named volumes](https://madcoda.com/2016/03/docker-named-volume-explained/):

```
docker run -it --privileged -v some_named_volume:/app/config -p 8083:8083 myapp-ubuntu:2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Dockerfile 
with directive COPY